# How to take Motorola Photon 4g out of the grave?

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, motorola-photon

Recently I ordered Motorola 4g from US.... It was with stock Sprint Sunfire OS.

```
OS       : Sunfire-2.3.5
Baseband : 4.5.1A (I am not sure about this whether its baseband or revision)
Build    : 1_SUN-254_4
```

**NOW ITS DEAD.... running in RSD Mode**

So what I did, I was trying to install custom rom on that. Steps I had taken

1. Rooted phone via installing SuperUser and various rooting methods like ClickOnce, Photon -Torpedo but no one seems successful , while executing I got errors everytime. But after day or two I came to know about that my phone is rooted. As I was getting SuperUser popups on root operations. Then I installed CWM and tried to install the ROM from there but everytime I got stucked at Yellow Triangular icon (recovery mode).
2. Repeated step on rooting process and unlocking the bootloader by applying pudding.rar and fastboot commands and every time i got the error and Starting RSD Screens, but anyhow my phone recovers itself to its original boot state afetr pulling out battery and manually restrating.
3. Finally one day I use some other Recovery Tool , i am unable to recall the name. It installed and rebooted successfully in the recovery mode. I then wipe the dalvik cache, wipe factory reset and then tried to installl the custom rom that MIUI 2.68 i think . I was happy to see some designer screens on my phone and then it said rom installed successfully.
4. I then reboot my phone and found it in the Failed To Start2 , Starting RSD mode

I tried various way to restore...

1. Installing pudding.rar using RSD lite but everytime I got sec_exception : sec_exception : b655, eddc,eb
2. I then tried reinstalling SBF : 1FF-sunfire-user-2.3.4-4.5.1A-1_SUN-198_7-CM-release-keys-signed-Sprint-US.sbf and sunfire-2.3.5-4.5.1A-1_SUN-254_4 but while enumerating phone 
   I got error  sec_exception febe 4e 4e

I have also tried nopudding4u.sbf but the same result.

Please,, help me and my phone out .. as its going to be more than a week... i feel handicaaped...

Please guide me through the step by step  , which file and when and please do provide the links of the files to download.

```
**Update OTA with 2.3.5 before murdering.....**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it back. For answer check the XDA Forum with same question.. ANybody in same condition [.. please visit the link..](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1849526)

Comment: Which link? I would be nice if you could add the information here too, in order to prevent link rot.

Comment: @Flow : thanks for pointing out the missing part.